# Find the volume of an object using integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

How am I supposed to find the volume of an object when I know that:
       $$x^2+y^2\le z^2, \ 0 \leq x, \ 0 \leq y, \ 0 \leq z \leq 1$$

Comment: Have you tried to figure out what the object looks like? It's one fourth of a figure I'm pretty certain you know how to calculate the volume of.

Comment: Basically you'd want to use cylindrical coordinates:

$\int_{z=0}^{z=1}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{r=0}^{r=z}rdrd \theta dz$

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze The $x \geq 0, y\geq 0$ constraint means that you want $\int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = \pi/2}$ instead.

Comment: So is the answer pi/12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to look at the cut's of the plains that parallel to x-y plain. let's also neglect $x,y > 0$ constraint at that moment.

the integral you have to solve is:  $$\iiint  1 \,dx\,dy\,dz$$

you can integrate the cut, as I previously said.

$$\iiint  1 \,dx\,dy\,dz = \int_{0}^{1}dz*\iint_{x^2+y^2 < z^2} dxdy$$
each cut, we have the area of disk with radius $z$.(because $x^2+y^2 < z^2$). the area of that disk is $\pi*z^2$,so all you have to do now is:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \pi z^2 dz$$

so the answer is $\pi/3$
in your question you added that $x,y > 0$ so you have exactly $1/4$ disk at each cut so , divide  $\pi/3$ by $4$ and you get $\pi/12$

Comment: So is the intregal showed by @ArtificialBreeze correct for that problem,cause i think its answer is pi/12...

Comment: I have edited my answer. it is indeed $\pi/12$.

Comment: and yes, the integral of ArtificialBreeze is correct. I solved it another way without  cylindrical coordinates

Comment: if we had x^2+y^2<=z instead x^2+y^2<=z^2 how to problem would change?

Comment: follow my solution. you will see,, that you should integrate $\pi zdz$ instead of $\pi z^2dz$. so you would get bigger answer by $1.5$ which means $\pi /8$